# Return jQuery Promise from AJAX get request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services

I'm trying to send a GET request to my localhost via an AJAX call and return the promise object and then play around with it. (The data is coming from a function web service call).  I added the following to my web.config file and it seemed to the the 'no get request allowed' error:

```
<system.web>
    <webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
      </protocols>
    </webServices>
  </system.web>
```

JS

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            function fetch() {
                var data = { firstName: 'd' };
                return $.ajax({
                    url: "../../Service.asmx/GetPersonsByName",
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (results) {
                        console.log(results.d);
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions) {
                        console.log(xhr);
                        console.log(ajaxOptions);
                    }
                });
            };
            fetch().done(function () {
                console.log('finished');
            }).fail(function () {
                //fails
                console.log('fails :(');
            });
        });
```

With this code I get the error that there's a missing parameter.  Web service method for good measure:

```
        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod]
        public List<Person> GetPersonsByName(string firstName)
        {
            var personList = new List<Person>();
            string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbcs"].ConnectionString;
            using (var con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetPersonsByName", con))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", firstName);
                    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        Person p = new Person();
                        p.PersonId = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["PersonId"]);
                        p.FirstName = rdr["FirstName"].ToString();
                        p.LastName = rdr["LastName"].ToString();
                        personList.Add(p);
                    }
                }
            }
            return personList;
        }
```

The web service works, so what I'm pretty sure is the URL  of the webservice that's at fault:
`GET http://localhost:58268/Service.asmx/GetPersonsByName?{%22firstName%22:%22d%22} 500 (Internal Server Error)`.

EDIT: the stored procedure I'm using works.

I tried to append $.param(data) to the URL and that didn't work either.  What's the best way to get this working?  Should I append the data I want to the URL?  Do I need to include it on the AJAX object?  I've tried various things with various degrees of non-success and I'm looking for the overarching theme here that I'm not implementing correctly.

Comment: A 500 error is a server error and has nothing to do with the ajax call.

Comment: Are you sure you're supposed to be stringifying your form data? you typically only need to do that if your service is expecting json.

Comment: @KevinB nope! I'm not sure.  I was trying to follow an example of a JS twitter application, but twitter's API isn't so easy to use anymore and I thought I'd issue get requests on my localhost and this is the first time I've tried and obviously don't grok everything.